# Problem booting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS iso file

Tags: boot, 20.04

Download Ubuntu 20.04 LTS iso file from ubuntu.com cheksum the file then made a start up USB
disk.
Booting the new burned USB it goes through the process stops with Focal Fossa sketch and time on Top Bar with four icons on the end no Dock and only the cursor which can be moved but nothing happens on clicking fter 20 seconds the screen goes black with only ubuntu name at the bottom.

Download ubuntu 3 times two with bittorrent and one direct from ubuntu.com with same results when
trying to boot with.
Why there is problems with this download and  how to get this fixed?
Thank you.
OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and validation was complete.

Comment: please [edit] you question to indicate which os you are using to create the bootable usb. [This tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) may be helpful.

Comment: Did you validate the ISO?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  though in my experience the write to your media is more likely to fail (so did it's validation complete?  if it didn't I'd blame the write, and confirm that by letting it validate itself on another box (or two)). You can switch to terminal and explore the issues too, did you try that?  (ctrl+alt+f4 etc)

Comment: Which tool or method did you use to create the live system in the USB disk? What computer is it (brand name and model)? What graphics chip/card is it (brand name and model)? Did you turn off secure boot? Did you try with the USB disk in another computer? -- There can be many reasons why it does not work for you. See this link: [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/)